# how to remember inputs value by using local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to use local storage to remember the input's value after refreshing page. but my code does not work.

here is the HTML code

```
<input type="text" name="name" onkeyup="saveValue(event)"/> 
<input type="text" name="name" onkeyup="saveValue(event)"/> 
<input type="text" name="age" onkeyup="saveValue(event)"/>
```

and here is javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nameArr = ["name"];
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('name');
inputs.forEach(function(el){
    el.value = getSavedValue(el);  
})

function saveValue(e) {
  var name = e.target.name;
  var val = e.target.value;
  localStorage.setItem(name, val);
}

function getSavedValue(v) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
    return "";
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(v);
}
</script>
```

if there is a way to solve this problem please tell me.
and if there is a way to do that with jquery I will be thankful to tell me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your code you are passing the input object as a parameter instead of its name (or value; you choose). As localStorage only stores String key-value pairs, it won't work as you're trying to find a key that is an object.

in the forEach instead of:

`el.value = getSavedValue(el);`

set:

`el.value = getSavedValue(el.name);`

or let the "getSavedValue" function accept an object as parameter, but to access localStorage you must pass a string as the key.

Answer (score 2):

Here are couple of things. First instead of `onkeyup` use `onblur` so value will be saved in storage only when the focus is removed from the element.

Secondly use a common class `inputs` in this case and give separate `name` to each element.

Then get all the elements with same class, iterate through it and get value of  `name` property using `getAttribute`. Use this value to check if there exist a key in `localStorage`

```js
var nameArr = ["name"];
var inputs = [...document.getElementsByClassName('inputs')];
inputs.forEach(function(el) {
  console.log()
  el.value = getSavedValue(el.getAttribute('name'));
})

function saveValue(e) {
  var name = e.target.name;
  var val = e.target.value;
  localStorage.setItem(name, val);
}

function getSavedValue(v) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
    return "";
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(v);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class='inputs' name="firstName" onblur="saveValue(event)" />
<input type="text" class='inputs' name="lastName" onblur="saveValue(event)" />
<input type="text" class='inputs' name="age" onblur="saveValue(event)" />
```

Comment: Is there a meaning to the `...` at beginning of the inputs array?

Comment: better selector for the inputs `var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name]');`

Comment: @crashwap The `...` is deconstructing the array-like results from the getElementsByClassName, and using them to construct a true Array.

Comment: @IvanKaraman Using the class makes it more flexible to matching things that are not tagName `input`

Comment: @crashwap its feature of es6, it calls array destructuring